# How to create an array of structs containing large arrays?

Tags: arrays, struct, rust

How could I create an array of structs containing big arrays with a fixed size? I want to use arrays and not vectors.

This code is an example but doesn't compile

```
struct _Tmove {
    data1: usize,
    data2: u64,
    data3: bool,
}

struct _TmoveP {
    data4: Box<[_Tmove]>,
    data5: isize,
}

fn main() {
    let mut gen_list = Box::new([
        _TmoveP {
            data5: 1,
            data4: Box::new([_Tmove { data1: 5, data2: 1, data3: true }; 300]),
        }
        ; 100000]);

    assert!(gen_list[0].data4[0].data1==5);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `_Tmove: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
--> src/main.rs:16:29
       |
    16 |             data4: Box::new([_Tmove { data1: 5, data2: 1, data3: true }; 300]),
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied

error[E0277]: the trait bound `_TmoveP: std::marker::Copy` is not     satisfied
--> src/main.rs:13:33
    |
13  |     let mut gen_list = Box::new([
    |                                 ^
    |
    = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied
```

I am using Rust 1.12.

Comment: Did you see the error from the compiler? It says, "the trait bound `_TmoveP: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied [...] note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied". Does that make it clearer?

Comment: adding  #[derive(Copy)] at two structs
the error is:
    error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
     --> src/main.rs:8:10
      |
    8 | #[derive(Copy)]
      |          ^^^^ field `data4` does not implement `Copy`
    src/main.rs:8:10: 8:14 note: in this expansion of #[derive(Copy)]     (defined in src/main.rs)

Comment: X-posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/56a91d/struct_of_structs_with_array/

Answer (score 3):

In order to benefit from the initialization syntax: `[expr; N]`, the result of `expr` need to be `Copy` (as copies need be made).

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct _Tmove {
    data1: usize,
    data2: u64,
    data3: bool,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct _TmoveP {
    data4: Box<[_Tmove]>,
    data5: isize,
}
```

However, in this case, `_TmoveP` *cannot* be `Copy` because it contains a `Box` which is not `Copy`.

Alright, let's get rid of `Box`:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct _TmoveP {
    data4: [_Tmove; 300],
    data5: isize,
}
```

Sounds great?

But unfortunately, `[_Tmove; 300]` is not `Clone` either :( We are unfortunately hitting a limitation of the Rust compiler (it works for size less than 32).

The `Copy` is easy enough... but first we have to implement `Clone` manually. The naive way is no fun, but it's easy enough:

```
impl Clone for _TmoveP {
    fn clone(&self) -> _TmoveP {
        unsafe {
            let mut res = _TmoveP {
                data4: std::mem::uninitialized(),
                data5: self.data5,
            };

            std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
                &self.data4 as *const _Tmove,
                std::mem::transmute(&mut res.data4),
                300
            );

            res
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: for some reason `&mut res.data4 as *mut _` would not compile... whatever :x*

However, [@Francis Gagné](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234590/francis-gagn%c3%a9) reminded me in the comments, there is a weird trick with `Copy` types:

```
impl Clone for _TmoveP {
    fn clone(&self) -> _TmoveP { *self }
}
```

This works, for some reason, and is handy in those situations.

And, finally, this works... oh wait, there's an issue in `main`!

```
fn main() {
    let gen_list = Box::new([
        _TmoveP {
            data5: 1,
            data4: [_Tmove { data1: 5, data2: 1, data3: true }; 300],
        }
        ; 100000]);

    assert!(gen_list[0].data4[0].data1==5);
}
```

Alright, [here we go](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e052d83bb94ba1dbb9543cc407ae7501&version=stable&backtrace=0).

---

What's the deal with arrays only really working for sizes smaller than 32?

Simply put: Rust does not have (yet?) support for non-type generic parameters.

Arrays are special-cased, to an extent, but require implementing traits for each size independently... so the standard library implements its traits for arrays up to size 32, because it seemed a good trade-off.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I found that `[T; N]` is **always** `Copy` as long as `T` is `Copy`, but it's only `Clone` up to N = 32.

Comment: @Aurora0001: Right! It's not `Clone` however, which means that `_TmoveP` cannot be `Clone`, and it thus cannot be `Copy`. Stupid... Stupid... :(

Comment: If you can derive `Copy` on a type, you can trivially implement `Clone` by returning `*self`.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Oh! I remember reading about that, but I completely missed it here. SO much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving this error because you're trying to initialise an array with the *default initialisation* syntax, but your struct does not implement the `Copy` trait, so this is not allowed. You can see the reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876588/why-is-the-copy-trait-needed-for-default-struct-valued-array-initialization), but, in a nutshell, the default initialisation syntax will create one copy of your struct, then try to copy it 100,000 times. Obviously, this isn't allowed if your struct isn't marked `Copy`, so an error is raised.

Normally, this could be solved by marking both your structs as `Copy`, like so:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct _Tmove {
    data1: usize,
    data2: u64,
    data3: bool,
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct _TmoveP {
    data4: Box<[_Tmove]>,
    data5: isize,
}
```

However, you'll notice that this still doesn't compile, because you've not actually got an array here. You've actually used the type for a slice ([take a look at this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262970/array-as-a-struct-field)). Slices **don't** implement `Copy`, so your code cannot compile because the `_TmoveP` struct can only derive `Copy` if all its fields are `Copy`.

It's unclear whether the array will **always** have a fixed size. If it will, then you need to use the type `[T; N]`, where `T` is your type and `N` is the number of elements (e.g. `[i32; 300]`). If not, you need a `Vec<T>`.

If you use an array, you hit *yet another problem*. Arrays implement `Copy` (up to 32), but not `Clone`, and we need to implement `Clone` for `_TmoveP` before we can implement `Copy`. So, let's do it ourselves:

```
impl Clone for _TmoveP {
    fn clone(&self) -> _TmoveP {
        _TmoveP {
            data4: self.data4,
            data5: self.data5
        }
    }
}
```

You can then remove the `#[derive(Clone)]` from `_TmoveP` (just leaving `Copy`), and we finally reach a working solution! [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f0467818bb4ce5202e545d78e148311a&version=stable&backtrace=0) is the playground link for my solution.

Comment: with rust 1.11 cargo build generates a very big executable witch 1.12 generares a small executable but goes in Segmentation fault

Comment: That's odd; it seems to work fine in the playground. Be aware that you are allocating ~16 bytes for each `_Tmove` struct, then storing 300 of those and another 8 bytes for an `isize`, so about 4,800 bytes per `_TmoveP`. You're then copying that **100,000** times, which allocates about **450MB** of space. I wonder if that causes some issues; LLVM might be statically generating the array contents which would cause your executable to blow up in size.